# Date function producing incorrect output

Tags: php

Can anyone help?
Why does this code produce the wrong answer?

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime("third monday", mktime(0,0,0,8,1,2016)));
echo '<br/>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime("third monday 2016-08" ));
```

Results for both lines is:

```
08/22/2016
```

The third Monday of August 2016 is actually `08/15/2016`
In addition it produces incorrect results for the third Monday of any month where the 1st is on a Monday.

It works if the 1st is not a Monday.

Comment: What's weird is that if you do `monday 2016-08` it does `08/01/2016` like it should do, but if you do `first monday 2016-08` it goes to `08/08/2016`...

Comment: The third Monday after 2016-08-01 is 2016-08-22, so it's giving you exactly the advertised result.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, but I can't tell you why it is acting up the way you're doing it... Hopefully someone else can explain why.

```
echo '<br/>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime("third monday of August 2016" ));
echo '<br/>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime("third monday of 2016-08" ));
```

Using `third monday OF` will get it to work.

Comment: Thanks the fixed worked as you I don't know why mine only failed if the first is a Monday.

Comment: It happens on all `first`, if you try `first tuesday 2016-08` you get the wrong date too! @Richard

Answer (score 0):

Found this explanation:
observe that the "of" in "ordinal space dayname space 'of' " and "'last' space dayname space 'of' " does something special.

It sets the day-of-month to 1.
  "ordinal dayname 'of' " does not advance to another day. 
   (Example: "first tuesday of july 2008" means "2008-07-01"). "ordinal dayname " does advance to another day. 
(Example: "first tuesday july 2008" means "2008-07-08",

("ordinal dayname" does advance to another day. 
(Example "first wednesday july 23rd, 2008" means "2008-07-30"). )

"'last' dayname 'of' " takes the last dayname of the current month. 
(Example: "last wed of july 2008" means "2008-07-30")

```
"'last' dayname" takes the last dayname from the current day.
```

(Example: "last wed july 2008" means "2008-06-25"; "july 2008" 
first sets the current date to "2008-07-01" and then "last wed" moves to the previous Wednesday which is "2008-06-25").